# Automatically generated plots with Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am currently using Mathematica to generate several plots later included in a LaTeX document. The process of exporting each of the graphs to eps/pdf and including these in the document is quite cumbersome, so I wonder if there is a standard way to automate it.

I would like to have an environment `mathematica` which can be used as follows.

```
\begin{mathematica}
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
\end{mathematica}
```

Ideally, the output graphic should be cached to avoid starting the expensive Mathematica process every time.

Comment: I use Mathematica to make most of my figures.  I find that except for the most trivial things, like your example, it takes a considerable amount of code to generate the perfect, publication quality figure, and it will be very inconvenient for you to write and test all that Mathematica code in a LaTeX document.  Exporting from Mathematica is easy and automatable: you can have a notebook which exports all figures when you run it.  If you [make them to size](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12), you just need to re-run your notebook when your figure changes, and recompile your ...

Comment: ... LaTeX document, and you're done!  Of course it's your choice how you'll solve the problem, but I think this way of working is going to be much more efficient than what you propose (Mathematica code in LaTeX).  Probably the biggest hurdle with the code-in-latex way will be that all of the snippets might depend on a fairly large set of variables (data) and functions that needs to be defined.  These snippets won't be able to share Mathematica's internal state, and you'd need to make each of them load/evaluate the definitions.

Comment: LaTeX should replace Mathematica? A strange joke...

Comment: (Did you export the plots using the GUI?  If so, that is indeed cumbersome.  Use the `Export` command instead to automate things and gain a lot of flexibiliy...)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I guess that he is looking for an interpreter rather than an emulation of Mathematica.

Comment: Do you really need Mathematica? If you want to plot sin(x), `pgfplots` is great. If you want to do symbolic integration, you could use `pythontex`'s sympy or `sagetex`.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips. I guess I was envisioning something very similar to `sagetex' but with Mathematica.

@Szabolcs: You make a good point that it is better to create a notebook with several Export statements and then re-run it as necessary. This may be better since the latex compilation is no longer dependent on Mathematica.

Comment: [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex), which is similar to `sagetex`, currently supports Python, Ruby, and Julia. I hope to add Mathematica support eventually. If you want Mathamatica in LaTeX, you might look into extending the [relevant part of `pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/blob/master/pythontex/pythontex_engines.py) (end of file). This mostly involves creating language-specific templates (maybe around 100 lines for full language support, plus possibly a few tweaks elsewhere). Any language that is added will automatically get `pythontex`'s support for caching.